# How to correctly utilize the timezone option in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Long story short:
I want to show the dates in the x-axis based on my customer timzeone which is coming from the server i.e 'Asia/Calcutta' ..etc
I have set `useUTC` to `false` and provided the timezone like this:

```js
time:{
  useUTC: false,
  timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta',
}
```

[image]

Yet, I see Highchart is handling the DST transition and I can see 1 hour is missing from the x-axis because of my own time zone which is "Europe/London".

Note; There's no DST in use in 'Asia/Calcutta' timezone

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Sayed110/o2s0y64f/57/

Comment: I think that it is a bug, could you report it on the Highcharts Github issue channel? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: @SebastianWędzel 
It turned out that I needed to use UTC dates in iso format.
and also I needed to set `useUTC` to true.
Highcharts  documentation not clear at all 

when I converted my dates to UTC and provided the correct timezone; I start to see the correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set `useUTC` to `true` and convert my dates to UTC.
and that was enough to fix the issue.